# distinct record with another distinct record from different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two fields that have records that are repeated many times.  I need to select a distinct record from one field and then match it with a random record (claim number) for that provider id.  So far I am having a difficult time with this.  The following definitely is not working.

```
  Select Distinct
  a.Provider_Id, a.Prov_Name, MIN(a.claim_number)

 from maindb a
 where a.PROV_st='MA'
 and a.Provider_Id <> ''
 group by a.Legacy_Provider_Id, a.Original_Claim_Number, a.Prov_Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a group by. Without it you cannot use an aggregate function. Try adding

Group by a.Provider_Id, a.Prov_Name

After your and statement.

Comment: I was about to suggest `GROUP BY` as well. Note that if you do that, then you don't need the `DISTINCT` anymore.

Comment: still getting repeating records.  I had the grp by function in the original code but cut it off on here when i copy/pasted on accident.

Comment: Why are you grouping by claim number as well? This will effectively negate the point of min and give you a row for each unique combination of provider, provider name and claim I'd which would result in duplicate rows. For instance if you have a  provider A with name ABC who had two claims 1, 2. You will get 2 rows back with A ABC 1

Comment: @user4152136 you were right...my bad, i know better than that and now feel like an idiot.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I was wondering what i was doing wrong since i do this a decent amount. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A min is an aggregation, that can be done only one single field query, or with group by clause.

In you case you could group by provider_id and prov_name (provided that prov_name is uniquely define by provider_id.

```
select provider_id, prov_name, min(claim_number)
from maindb
where prov_st = 'MA'
and provider_id <> ''
group by provider_id, prov_name
```

That should do the trick

Comment: i edited the origininal code i posted to include the grp by since i used that originally when i ran the code.  I am still getting lots of repeats.  The claim_no field can have many iterations, if that makes sense?

Comment: Where do you get your repeat, in which field?